# AngularJS: Return different values for $http success() or error()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, angular-promise, angular-http

In a controller I have this function:

```
bar.updateData = function(val) {
    $http.put('url/foo/', {
        param   : val
    }).success(function(data){
        return true;
    }).error(function(data){
        return 'this is a string';
    });
};
```

I need to return `true` or a string depending on the callback `success()` or `error()`. I wrote that code but seems not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accepted answer is right but also wrong (it gives you the correct code but doesn't explain the reasoning as to why this won't work). `$http.put` *does* return a promise that gives you `success` and `error` callbacks. The information in that answer is just flat out incorrect.

You can't return values from `success` and `error` because they are **callbacks** and not part of the A+ promise standard. They do not chain, because they do not return a new promise each time you invoke them, they instead return the same promise.

For this reason, you should more-or-less always use `then`/`catch` - both of these play well with other non-`$http` promises and are standard methods. They also support chaining because `then` and `catch` will return a new version of the promise with each subsequent invocation - so the return value from the first `then` will be passed to the second `then` (and so forth).

The code that @Pankaj has posted is more or less correct, I would make a minor modification and use `catch` instead of passing two callbacks to `then` because it is easier to scan.

```
bar.updateData = function(val) {
  return $http.put('url/foo', { param: val })
    .then(function(res) {
      return res.data;
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      return 'this is a string';
    });
};
```